# How to generate parameter packs via meta-programming?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

Suppose

```cpp
template<T,typename... Types> void bar(Types..., int,Types...,float,T);
```

I am trying to write a template struct GimmePack<double,k> so that

```cpp
bar<char, GimmePack<double,3>::type >(x,y,z,42,dx,dy,dz,3.14159,'c');
```

is the same as

```cpp
bar<char, double,double,double >(x,y,z,42,dx,dy,dz,3.14159,'c');
```

I.e., I would like to find a way to repeat a Template type k times outside of a tuple type, i.e. directly injecting it into a function.

I had left out the arguments priorly because their exact nature is of no relevance to the question. But as has turned out from the below answers (some of which become inapplicable from that fact), the fact of the mere existance of a nontrivial signature based on `Types...` is a critical detail.

## Question

Is this even possible?

Below is my attempt.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

template<typename,size_t,typename...> struct Packstack;

template<typename Tfloat, size_t i, typename ...Types>
    requires(i>0)
struct Packstack<Tfloat,i,Types...>{
    using pack = typename Packstack<Tfloat,i-1,Tfloat,Types...>::pack;
};

template<typename Tfloat, typename ...Types>
struct Packstack<Tfloat,0,Types...>{
    using pack... = Types...;
};

template<typename Tfloat, size_t i>
struct GimmePack{
    using pack = typename Packstack<Tfloat,i>::pack;
};
```

## Remarks

I am aware that I could weave my Packstack metaprogramming code into the function definition of bar.
But in my actual source code that I am developing on, bar is not a simple function but a template function of a complicated template class, and readability would suffer.

I am also aware that the information `double,double,double` is equivalent to the information `double,3` in my context of identical types, hence a template specialization for `bar` could be constructed if bar was a struct (because template specializations for functions are invalid c++). So my question is rather on syntax and not on concept.

## What I tried

In my actual code I have already tried rearranging the order of the templates so that the compiler could figure them out, but my signature is

```cpp
template<typename other1, typename other2, typename ...Values> bar(Values... values1, other1 o1, Values... values2, other2 o2);
```

and it just seems like whenever Values... appears twice in a signature then the compiler wants to have it written explicitly. While it looks like vectors are a good choice here, the data elements within each values1..., values2... stem from uncorrelated contexts.

I tried putting triple-dots in various places around the using statements.

Comment: You could generate an intermediate `std::tuple` and then specialise your `template`  for it so it forwards to the types to the one accepting a parameter pack.

Comment: @Erel. I agree if bar was a struct, but bar is a function. I can of course wrap a struct around bar but that further bloats it. You meant that, right?, i.e. ``template<typename... Typles> bar<tuple<Types...>>();`` if that were possible.

Comment: Yeah, for example. You could have a helper `struct` in a `namespace detail` to do this so that it doesn't get exposed "too much".

Comment: C++'s pack expansion doesn't work that way. You need to have a parameter pack (`auto... ps` or `typename... Ts`) in order for expansion to work. You can't have `typename SomeTuple::type` be expanded in a way you want. You need at least a wrapper that will represent your type as a parameter pack that can be expanded (`Tuple -> Ts...`). The esiest way to do it with `std::apply` and an identity class in your case

Comment: Why do you need explicit template specialization for the arguments whose types are automatically deduced? What is the actual problem?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik that particular function template in the example will fail automatic deduction, feel free to try it. It will deduce `Types` as an empty pack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using an explicit template parameter list on a generic lambda expression?

```cpp
template <class...>
struct mp_list {};

template <class, std::size_t>
struct mp_pack {};

namespace detail {

template <class L, class...>
struct mp_expand { using type = L; };

template <class... Ts, class U, class... Us>
struct mp_expand<mp_list<Ts...>, U, Us...>
    : mp_expand<mp_list<Ts..., U>, Us...> {};

template <class... Ts, class U, std::size_t I, class... Us>
struct mp_expand<mp_list<Ts...>, mp_pack<U, I>, Us...>
    : mp_expand<mp_list<Ts..., U>, mp_pack<U, I - 1>, Us...> {};

template <class... Ts, class U, class... Us>
struct mp_expand<mp_list<Ts...>, mp_pack<U, 0>, Us...>
    : mp_expand<mp_list<Ts...>, Us...> {};

}  // namespace detail

template <class... Ts>
using mp_expand = typename detail::mp_expand<mp_list<>, Ts...>::type;

template <class... Ts>
auto GimmePack(auto f) {
  return f(mp_expand<Ts...>{});
}
```

and then:

```cpp
template <class T, class... Types>
void bar(Types..., int, Types..., float, T);

// bar<char, double, double, double>(x, y, z, 42, dx, dy, dz, 3.14159, 'c');
GimmePack<char, mp_pack<double, 3>>([&]<class... Ts>(mp_list<Ts...>) {
  return bar<Ts...>(x, y, z, 42, dx, dy, dz, 3.14159, 'c');
});
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x1fWWW79Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable template.

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, int N>
struct GimmePack{
    using type = decltype(
        std::apply([](auto... args){
            return std::tuple{args...};
        },
    std::array<T, N>{}))>);
}

template<typename T, typename... Types>
void bar(Types..., int,Types..., float, T){
    //...
}

template<typename, typename>
void (*make_bar)() = nullptr;

template<typename T, typename... Types>
void (*make_bar<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>)(Types..., int, Types..., float, T) = bar<T, Types...>;

template <typename... Args>
void caller(Args... args){
   make_bar<int, std::tuple<double, double>>(args...); // equivalent to bar<int, double, double>(args...);
   make_bar<int, GimmePack<double, 2>::type>(args...); // same
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is just an idea:

Have you tried template specialization and recursion?

```
// The type is (T) and count is (N).
template<typename T, int N>
struct MyStruct {
    using type = typename MyStruct<T, N - 1>::type;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyStruct<T, 0> {
    using type = T;
};
```

Now we use `MyStruct` to generate the desired parameter pack for `bar` function:

```
template<typename... Types>
void bar();

using MyPack = typename MyStruct<double, 3>::type;
bar<MyPack>();
```

Comment: I think that MyStruct<double,3>::type is merely double. You would need triple-dots somewhere in your code in order to generate a list of doubles that varies with the length parameter, in your case N. You probably mean that my function interface could be as well std::array<double,N> then, but this just leads to a different function signature needed for bar then, in that now it is bar(x1,...,xN,u,y1,...,yN,v) whereas in your case bar({x1,...,xN},u,{y1,...,yN},v). (Thanks for your answer. I did not downvote and never would.)